# Remove Pass Type Identifier (Apple Certificates)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, code-signing-certificate, apple-wallet

If I remove a Pass Type Identifier that is linked with a production (currently live) Pass Type ID certificate, will it affect my production pass certificate?

When I press delete it states: "**Delete Pass Type ID**"

"Deleting this Pass Type ID will prevent you from sending future updates to any associated passes. Installed passes will not be affected."

But I want to make sure I will not be breaking anything in production.

Any help?
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may have figured this out by now, but deleting a pass type id does not invalidate previous passes that were installed nor does it prevent new passes that use it from being installed so long as you do not revoke or remove the associated certificates.

Comment: Wrote a bit more on it here: https://www.passninja.com/tutorials/apple-platform/what-happens-when-an-apple-pass-type-id-is-deleted